# Using alarmmanager, how to camera preview record on android

Tags: android

I want camera preview record every 2 o'clock.

so, I use alarmManager first.

```
String rec_time = "14:00";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   .
   setAlarmTime(this);
}
private void setAlarmTime(Context context) {

   String[] strRec = rec_time.split(":");
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(strRec[0]));
   cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(strRec[1]));
   cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
   PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(0, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pending); 
}
```

this source is when two o'clock starts `AlarmReceiver.class.' 
in other words, another execute the class.

but I want when two o'clock execute camera preview record.

previously I coding camera preview record method.
`mCapturing.initCapturing(1, 1, 1, 1)`;

To summarize, use AlarmManager, when 2 o'clock , execute `mCapturing.initCapturing();`

how to solve this problem?

thanks.